# OpenCL type conversion from vector types to boolean

Tags: opencl

For the statement in my OpenCL kernel

```
uint4 checkCoord; // assign some value
if(checkCoord==(uint4)(0,0,0,0)){
  ; // do something
}
```

I am getting the following error in OpenCL compiler

```
statement requires expression of scalar type ('int  __attribute__((ext_vector_type(4,4)))' invalid)
```

What is the easiest way to convert a variable of uint4 type to a bool (or scalar) value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `all` to test the condition is verified on all components of the vector. `checkCoord == (uint4)(0,0,0,0)` is an int4 with components either `0` (false) or `(uint)-1` (true).

```
if ( all( checkCoord == (uint4)(0,0,0,0) ) ) { ... }
```

According to the OpenCL specs (6.3.e), you could also write

```
if ( all( checkCoord == 0 ) ) { ... }
```